# I cannot pass more than one value in QueryString

Tags: asp.net, query-string

My ASP.NET application has stopped working after I migrated it to another server.

The problem is that I cannot send more than one value via the query string.

The URL I'm trying looks like this:

```
ThisIsSecondPage.aspx?Mode=Edit&ID=0001
```

I can capture the value of **Mode** in *ThisIsSecondPage.aspx*, but **ID** is blank.

I also tried to change **ID** to something line *A0001*, but it did not work.

I also tried:

```
ThisIsSecondPage.aspx?Mode=Edit<and>ID=0001
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: how to get querystring in ThisIsSecondPage.aspx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send querystring like this

```
ThisIsSecondPage.aspx?Mode=Edit&ID=0001
```

and recive in page_load event of  ThisIsSecondPage page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ModeParam = "";
        string IDparam = "";
        if(Request.Params["Mode"] !=null)
            ModeParam = Request.Params["Mode"].ToString();
        if (Request.Params["ID"] != null)
            IDparam = Request.Params["ID"].ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing query string correctly.

```
ThisIsSecondPage.aspx?Mode=Edit&ID=0001
```

In second page, Use as below

For Mode

```
string ModeValue = Request.QueryString["Mode"];
```

or in short form,

```
string ModeValue = Request["Mode"];
```

For ID

```
string IDValue = Request.QueryString["ID"];
```

or in short form,

```
string IDValue = Request["ID"];
```